Raylib_cs terminates after loading font to static member
I'm trying to load a font into an object that is a member of a static class in the C# binding of Raylib. My objective is to use a single static class accessible from across my entire project using a single namespace. I use Newtonsoft's JSON library to de-serialize my objects. Since I've had trouble de-serializing into a static class in a neat and compact way, I've resorted into a solution like this:
using Raylib_cs;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
namespace Game.Configs
{
    public static class Configuration
    {
        /*Debug config*/
        private static DebugConfig? _debug;
        public static DebugConfig Debug => _debug!;

        /*Graphics config*/
        private static GraphicsConfig? _graphics;
        public static GraphicsConfig Graphics => _graphics!;
        

        public static void Load(string Path)
        {
            try
            {
                _debug = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DebugConfig>(File.ReadAllText($"{Path}dbg.json"))!;
                _graphics = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GraphicsConfig>(File.ReadAllText($"{Path}gfx.json"))!;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Log the exception
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception during deserialization: {e}");
            }

        }
    }
    //these classes are in separate source files, but within the same namespace so I added them here
    public class DebugConfig
    {
        public string? FontPath {get; set;}
        [JsonIgnore]
        public Font DebugFont {get;set;}
        [OnDeserialized]
        internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FontPath))
                DebugFont = Raylib.LoadFont(FontPath);
        }
    }
    public class GraphicsConfig
    {
        public  string? Title {get; set;}
        public  V2Di Resolution {get;set;}
        public  bool Windowed {get;set;}
        public  byte Framerate {get;set;}
    }
}

And I have a "Game" class which is implemented like so:
partial class Game
{
    public Game()
    {
        Configuration.Load("res/cfg/");
    }
    public void Initialize()
    {
        Raylib.InitWindow(Configuration.Graphics.Resolution.X,Configuration.Graphics.Resolution.Y,Configuration.Graphics.Title);
        if(!Configuration.Graphics.Windowed && !Raylib.IsWindowFullscreen())
            Raylib.ToggleFullscreen();
        Raylib.SetTargetFPS(Configuration.Graphics.Framerate);
        Start();
    }
}

The Game constructor is called first thing in my program entry point. Running in debug, the program immediately terminates itself after raylib reporting a successful load of Configuration.Debug.DebugFont from said object's de-serialization callback method.
INFO: FILEIO: [res/fnt/_stmr.ttf] File loaded successfully
The program '[24301] rayNet' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Loading the font into it's own static variable within the "Game" class works just fine: public static Font ttfTest = Raylib.LoadFont("res/fnt/_stmr.ttf");
And the loading and use of Configuration.Graphics works as expected. Commenting out the line:
_debug = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DebugConfig>(File.ReadAllText($"{Path}dbg.json"))!; in the Configuration class prevents the application from terminating on load, and the de-serialized data for Configuration.Graphics works just fine.
There are no exceptions thrown on program termination, or any warnings when compiling. What causes Configuration.Graphics to work, but not
Configuration.Debug?

Turns out, despite the Raylib.LoadFont()being static, It can't be called before any other static Raylib methods that have anything to do with the initialization of Raylib. I've done a ghetto fix for the in the DebugConfig class for this, which checks the font's availability in it's getter:
public Font DebugFont;
public Font DFont
{
    get
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FontPath) && !Raylib.IsFontReady(DebugFont))
            DebugFont = Raylib.LoadFont(FontPath);
        return DebugFont;
    }
    set
    {
        DebugFont = value;
    }
}

This is an awful implementation, but since I'm only using this for debugging, this should suffice for now.
